# getting trace from ruby Net::HTTP with https

Tags: ruby, http

I'd love to be able to get a full HTTP trace from ruby's Net::HTTP for https.  At the moment I am inspecting stuff in the debugger like so:

```
(rdb:1) response
#<Net::HTTPFound 302 FOUND readbody=true>
(rdb:1) response.each_header {|x| puts x}
content-type
date
location
server
vary
content-length
connection
{"content-type"=>["text/html; charset=utf-8"], "date"=>["Wed, 28 Aug 2013 16:13:44 GMT"], "location"=>["https://example.com/login?next=/stuff"], "server"=>["nginx/1.1.19"], "vary"=>["Cookie"], "content-length"=>["0"], "connection"=>["keep-alive"]}
```

which is really helpful, but I'd just love to see the raw HTTP, e.g.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
```

etc.

Is there any way to just dump a copy of the HTTP requests and responses without going through intermediate processing to reconstruct them?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think it is impossible to get the raw HTTP headers from Net::HTTPResponse, because it parses the headers while it is receiving the data. See [HTTPResponse#read_new](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/net/1.9.3/Net/HTTPResponse.read_new)